# How can I run multiple apps of multiple bundle with foreman

Tags: ruby, bundler, foreman

I have a ruby app that depends of several web-services i've built.

To start all together I've got the following Procfile:

```
mondodb: /home/dwaynemac/mongodb/bin/mongod 
accounts: ./script/start_accounts.sh
contacts: ./script/start_contacts.sh
activity: ./script/start_activity_stream.sh
web: ./script/start.sh
```

Each of this start_xxx.sh script do something like:

```
cd ../activity_stream; bundle exec unicorn -p 3003 -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

If I manually run these previous line activity_stream runs ok. But when ran from foreman some gems are not recognized. As if the bundle was not correctly built.

Example error:

```
activity_stream/config/boot.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- grape (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [subcontractor gem](https://github.com/pitluga/subcontractor) to change working directory:

```
image_fallback: subcontract -d lib/rack/img_fallback/ -- bundle exec unicorn -c unicorn.conf config.ru
```

Comment: just learned of this gem, and it's fantastic! I used to have 3 tabs each running their own forman, but now have a single with everything. One thing to note is that now all logs show in one window, but that's manageable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a new bash shell for each app you want to boot up.

```
# Procfile
app1: sh -c 'cd path/to/app1 && bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT'
app2: sh -c 'cd path/to/app2 && bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT'
```

Then use foreman

```
foreman start --procfile path/to/Procfile
```

More info here http://www.seanbehan.com/how-to-boot-up-multiple-sinatra-applications-at-the-same-time-with-foreman